# AppleScript - Change prefs when home

Tags: applescript

Alright guys, so I have a script set up to turn off the "require password on wake" function when I am at home. It pings my phone to see if I am connected to the network, and if not turns on lock to wake. So:

```
try
do shell script "ping -c2 X.X.X.X"
set theResult to the result
if theResult contains " 2 packets received," then
    tell application "System Events"
        tell security preferences
            get properties
            set properties to {require password to wake:false, require password to unlock:false}
        end tell
    end tell
end if
on error
tell application "System Events"
    tell security preferences
        get properties
        set properties to {require password to wake:true, require password to unlock:true}
    end tell
end tell
end try
end
```

This works just fine, however it asks to authenticate. I don't really want to use the enter text & return route, nor the clipboard route, because I don't want the password in the script... so is there a way to avoid the authentication?

Comment: Can you store the password in Keychain?

Comment: What framework executes this script? Can you set this script file setuid-root and have it execute with elevated privileges? Or is this script file entirely interpreted by the surrounding framework?

Comment: @robert Already tried keychain. That's a no-go.

Comment: @sarnold I believe it relies on the Apple Carbon framework. Didn't even think about elevating privileges though! Going to give that a shot now, although I'm on a mac so no setuid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to enable/disable "password on wake" rather than to run that particular script without authentication, use either

```
tell application "System Events"
    set require password to wake of security preferences to true
end tell
```

or

```
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.screensaver -int 1"
```

and the same with "to false" and "-int 0" to turn the setting off. None of these require authentication, as they're simply changing a user-level preference (stored in

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist
```

on my system, though this is an implementation detail you shouldn't rely on).

What triggers the authentication dialog in your script is the other property, "require password to unlock", equivalent to the "Require an administrator password to access locked preferences" option in the "Advanced..." part of Security Preferences. Under the hood, *this* option is equivalent to changing a number of settings in the Authorization Services database,

```
/private/etc/authorization
```

controlling whether various *system-wide* preferences may be left unlocked for unauthenticated changes.

System Events does appear to have a (less serious) bug, however: on my systems, setting "require password to unlock" has no effect, whether I authenticate as an admin or not.

Comment: This was the more permanent solution I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this answer:

1. there is no way to pass the password, either via the script or via GUI Scripting, to the SecurityAgent application, which is in charge of the prompt (that is by design), nor can you suppress it altogether; this being said,
2. you can ignore the prompt and dismiss the window without inputting a password – your property settings will be applied even in that case (tested on OS X 10.7.4).

*Reported as a Security issue to Apple as [rdar://11484075](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1721406)*

*UPDATE: Apple Product Security does not consider this a security issue, but the bug itself is still tracked (I’ll have to guess, as it is closed as duplicate of another radar, which is not available on Openradar, but I’d expect the spurious dialog appearing to be the issue Apple has its eyes on).*

Comment: Oh great! That works. This is fine for now but I'll continue to search for a more permanent solution and I'll post it if I find it! Thanks